# Why does one web scraping search return correctly while others return none?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

I know this should be simple, which is why it's frustrating. I have searched through questions similar to this, and I do know what "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'" means.

I'm working on a web scraping script which grabs company titles, names, etc. from [this](http://www.homeopathycenter.org/professional-and-organizational-directory) website. The confusing this is, two search functions, for company title and for primary contact work perfectly, while any written for company name, email, and phone number do not. Even though all of these exist and the structure is the same as that for the searches that do work. Can anyone point out what's different about these?

My code is here, where the first two searched work but the third returns None. I'm new to python, and any help would be appreciated.

```
# import libraries
import urllib2  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv  
from datetime import datetime 

data = []
for i in range (0, 4):
    quote_page = 'http://www.homeopathycenter.org/professional-and-organizational-directory' + '?field_geofield_distance%5Bdistance%5D=50&field_geofield_distance%5Bunit%5D=3959&field_geofield_distance%5Borigin%5D=&field_professional_category_tid=All&combine=&field_address_locality=&field_address_administrative_area=&field_address_country=All&field_consultations_by_phone_value=All&field_consultations_online_value=All&field_animal_consultations_value=All&page={}'.format(i)

    page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page) 

    # parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    #identify full contact box
    box_array = ['views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first',
                'views-row views-row-2 views-row-even',
                'views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd',
                'views-row views-row-4 views-row-even',
                'views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd',
                'views-row views-row-6 views-row-even',
                'views-row views-row-7 views-row-odd',
                'views-row views-row-8 views-row-even',
                'views-row views-row-9 views-row-odd',
                'views-row views-row-10 views-row-even views-row-last']

    #loop the boxes
    for box in box_array:
        full_box = soup.find('div', {'class': box})

        #get title from box
        title_box = full_box.find('div', {'class': 'views-field views-field-title'})
        title_content = title_box.find('span', {'class': 'field-content'})
        title = title_content
        title = title.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing

        #get contact name from box, this works
        contact_box = full_box.find('div', {'class': 'views-field views-field-field-primary-contact'})
        contact_content = contact_box.find('div', {'class': 'field-content'})
        name = contact_content, this works
        name = name.text.strip()

        #get company name from box, this returns none
        company_box = full_box.find('div', {'class': 'views-field views-field-field-company-name'})
        company_content = company_box.find('div', {'class': 'field-content'})
        company = company_content.text.strip()
```

EDIT: the error code is as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\sc3.py", line 46, in 
    company_content = company_box.find('div', {'class': 'field-content'})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Can you please add the error because you ae using find function seven times. Your error should tell you which find is having a problem with. It could be that html is not consistent between the different pages. Just press F12 to check consistency on web browser.

Comment: I've added the error pointing to line 47. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: `company_box` is empty, try to print it out and see what it contains when it is failing.

Comment: It contains what it's meant to, but looking into it I found that some of the company names are blank, which causes it to fail further down the loop. Thanks for the advice - it helped to figure it out a lot.